# My App is not displayed in App Launcher in real device but works in AVD

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I've been looking at all the existing answers to this problem and haven't found an answer that works for me yet...

My android app is a simple "press a button, get fed a random quote" thing and I'm working in android studio.

The app works just fine in AVD, but when I generate an APK and try and install it on my phone, it does not allow me to open it, and doesn't display it anywhere in the launcher. It is displayed in the app settings, however, with my only option being to uninstall it.

I'll appreciate any help I can get!

This is my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.adamrath.openwhensad">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.adamrath.openwhensad.MainActivity"
    android:background="#252525">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/CheerText"
        android:id="@+id/mainText"
        android:layout_marginTop="204dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ButtonText"
        android:id="@+id/sadbtn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="@style/AppTheme"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which is the target API in your build.gradle (minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion) and which Android version has your device?

Comment: minSdkVersion is 19
targetSdkVersion is 23
My device is running Android 6.0

Comment: "but when I generate an APK.. " are you using terminal or Android studio to install the apk on the device?

Comment: I'm building a signed APK with android studio, then transferring it via usb to my phone, then installing it through a file browser there.